# Using Facebook API (via Symfony) leads to multiple post on my Page wall

Tags: php, facebook, symfony, facebook-graph-api, cron

I've got a problem while auto-posting my blog articles on Facebook. I've been looking everywhere on the web to find a solution but it seems I'm the only one to face this problem.

Here are all the informations:

- I am using Symfony 3 for my blog
- I save a "publicationDate" ($article->getPublicationDate()) to postpone article publication and a "hasBeenSentOnSocialNetworks" (($article->getIsOnline()) boolean to know if it has been sent on Twitter and Facebook wall
- I've set a controller action to check if there is any article to set online.
- When the controller is called, I get a list of offline articles (publicationDate < now AND getIsOnline == false)
- Each of them is then pushed on social networks, thanks to the great bundle of Martin Georgiev (https://github.com/martin-georgiev/social-post-bundle)
- Finally, I flush $article->setIsOnline(true) to avoid posting every time, once it's done.

Everything works just fine as Twitter publish my articles and Facebook too. My database saved isOnline = true.

With OVH I can only run CRON task every hour. The CRON task does the job perfectly with only 1 post published on social networks for every article. My CRON is calling a file that use curl to open the page of the controller that handles the publication.

But to have better reaction time, I've tried adding an event in Symfony so that every time a page is loaded, it checks if there are articles to publish on social networks. This worked fine, excepted I had 2 articles posted on Twitter and about 20-30 on Facebook... I've tried everyting : kernel.response, kernel.controller, kernel.request and I've made a "return;" if the event is not MASTER_REQUEST. No success.

Then I've decided to use twig to call the controller opened by my CRON task. I have added at the bottom of my base.html.twig a "{{ render(controller(....)) }}". It works fine for Twitter with only one post. But on Facebook it sends dozen of time the same publication.

I'm kinda lost. It's been days now that I am trying to fix that. Any help or advice would be appreciated! Thanks :)

My controller action:

```html
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Article::class);
$articles = $repository->findAllOfflineArticles();

  foreach ($articles as $article) {
    $content = $article->getSocialContent();

    if($content == null){
      $content = $article->getTitle();
    }

    $link = $this->get('router')->generate('article_show', array('slug' =>       $article->getSlug()), UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL);
    // Post on social networks
    $message = new \MartinGeorgiev\SocialPost\Provider\Message($content, $link);
    $this->get('social_post')->publish($message);
    //

    $article->setIsOnline(true);
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($article);
    $em->flush();
  }
```

---------------- **EDIT 1** ----------------

Thanks to @AhmetGunes for opening my eyes. I've been looking for the error everywhere in my code and I have tried so many different things that my understanding of the situation was blurred. It seems the problem was just as the following:

```html
public function findAllOfflineArticles(){
  return $this
   ->createQueryBuilder('a')
   ->where('a.isPublished = :is_published')
   ->andWhere('a.isValidated = :is_validated')
   ->andWhere('a.isOnline <= :is_online')
   ->andWhere('a.publicationDate <= :now')
   ->setParameter('now', new \Datetime())
   ->setParameter('is_published', true)
   ->setParameter('is_validated', true)
   ->setParameter('is_online', false)
   ->orderBy('a.publicationDate', 'ASC')
   ->getQuery()
   ->getResult()
  ;
}
```

The problem was obvious, despite I don't really understand how it was working this way.
The query was fetching

```
->andWhere('a.isOnline <= :is_online')
```

I corrected this big mistake :

```
->andWhere('a.isOnline = :is_online')
```

and got only one post on facebook!

However, why didn't Doctrine told me there was a problem with my request? How come the script wasn't launching again once isOnline was set to true ?

---------------- **EDIT 2** ----------------

The correction worked properly two times. But now it's back as before. Exactly 28-29 publications on Facebook. I'm definitively exhausted of this. This is driving me crazy.

Comment: Can you share the details of findAllOfflineArticles function?

Comment: @AhmetGunes, thank you very much for pointed that out! I've found a mistake that seems to have caused the multi-posting on Facebook. I've run a test article and it was all right. Cf. my post edit. :)

Comment: @AhmetGunes, in fact the problem is style there. I've got no idea what to do, what to try... Twitter is handling it just fine.

Comment: Did you check for duplicates on your DB?

Comment: There is no duplicate in the database. And most of the time there is only one article to publish each time the script is launched. I've got it fixed only by using CRON which uses the exact same script that is called from the cron.php file via the curl php property.

But this is does not explain the reason why I've got multiple posts at all. Maybe a problem with symfony?